# How to write two back-to-back (not simultaneous) multiprocessing.dummy tasks?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

Quick, stupid question:

What is the best way to write two back-to-back multiprocessing tasks, especially if they both use the same number of threads?

What I'm currently doing:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

pool = Pool(8)
pool.imap_unordered(do_something, data_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()

pool = Pool(8)
pool.imap_unordered(do_something_else, another_data_list)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Clarification for the comments below:

My first function, `do_something`, retrieves a bunch of `GET` urls and creates the list, `another_data_list`, for the second function, `do_something_else`. Therefore, I don't want to start the second pool until the first pool completely finishes.

Comment: There's no need to close the pool after your first call to a pool-method (a job) if you need it again for another job. Btw. `multiprocessing.dummy` is `multithreading`not `multiprocessing` and using `imap_unordered` without iterating over the results is kinda pointless.

Comment: @Darkonaut: Totally agree with the first part of your comment regarding multithreading, but suspect the results are not being used simply because this is just sample code. Regardless, the question title mentions that the OP wants to run to non-concurrent "tasks", so that may be why there's the a `join()` call between them—in other word what they may have really meant was "batches" of tasks.

Comment: It would be nice if the OP would comment and clarify what they're trying to accomplish—otherwise we can only guess...

Comment: Thanks guys, I added additional info on what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Just use `pool.map()` two times without closing the pool in between then. `map` is a blocking call, so the second call won't start before the first returns.

Comment: @Darkonaut Also I'm using `imap_unordered` since I'm wrapping that over `tqdm` like `for _ in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(do_something, data_list)): pass`. I tried `map` and the progress bar won't show up.

Comment: As long as you drain the iterator `tqdm.tqdm` returns like you showed, you can run two jobs sequentially without having to close and reopen a new pool between them. The iterations are what blocks then.